# JQuery Dialog box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery Dialog set up to a column in a grid to show data available on that column if it exceeds some limit. It's working for few values and for few others it's not displaying the dialog. Is there any constraint on number of characters to display or any parameter to set number of characters?

Following is the code i use for Dialog:

```
$.Dialog({
    overlay:true,
    shadow:true,
    title: title,
    content: contents,
    padding: 10,
    width:400,
    onShow: function(_dialog) { 
    }
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET?

Comment: Do you see any error on console , for the values it doesnt pop up the dialog ? as far as i understand there is no limit to number of characters on a dialog

Comment: Example data would be useful to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that data with path details are not displayed as I have not used escape sequence. Once I added escape sequence characters it worked!